# Verify matrix transpose using frama-c -wp

Tags: frama-c

I have an issue verifying functional correctness of a matrix transposition, and the issue is symptomatic of others I had using `frama-c -wp`. I am not sure how to enable Frama-C to reason better about memory separation. In other scenarios, I've resorted to inductive definitions (including `unchanged`), but I am wondering if I am missing something here.

Here is a program that verifies, minus the ensures clause about functional correctness. I tried carrying it as loop invariants, but there seems to be a problem and Frama-C gets confused by the memory separation.

So as a challenge, how would you verify matrix transposition?

```c
#define N 100

/*@
requires 0 < rows < N;
requires 0 < cols < N;
requires 0 <= r < rows;
requires 0 <= c < cols;
ensures 0 <= \result < rows*cols;
 */
int index(int rows, int cols, int r, int c) {
  return r*cols+c;
}

/*@
predicate inv(int *a, int rows, int cols) =
  0 < rows < N && 0 < cols < N && \valid(a+(0..rows*cols-1));
*/

/*@
requires inv(a, cols, rows);
requires inv(o, rows, cols);
requires \forall int i; \forall int j; 0 <= i < rows*cols && 0 <= j < rows*cols ==> \separated(a+i, o+j);
requires \forall int i; \forall int j; 0 <= i < rows*cols && i < j < rows*cols ==> \separated(o+i, o+j);

ensures \forall int r; \forall int c; 0 <= r < rows && 0 <= c < cols ==> o[r*cols+c] == a[c*rows+r];

assigns o[0..rows*cols-1];
 */
void transpose(int *a, int *o, int rows, int cols) {
  int r = 0;
  /*@
    loop invariant 0 <= r <= rows;
    loop assigns r, o[0..rows*cols-1];
    loop variant rows - r;
  */
  for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    /*@
      loop invariant 0 <= c <= cols;
      loop assigns c, o[r*cols..(r+1)*cols-1];
      loop variant cols - c;
    */
    for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
      o[r*cols+c] = a[c*rows+r];
    }
  }
}
```

For example, here are some invariants that enable the post condition to go through, but invariant 2, 4, 5 cannot be proved preserved.

```c
/*@
requires inv(a, cols, rows);
requires inv(o, rows, cols);
requires \forall int i; \forall int j; 0 <= i < rows*cols && 0 <= j < rows*cols ==> \separated(a+i, o+j);
requires \forall int i; \forall int j; 0 <= i < rows*cols && i < j < rows*cols ==> \separated(o+i, o+j);

ensures \forall int r; \forall int c; 0 <= r < rows && 0 <= c < cols ==> o[r*cols+c] == a[c*rows+r];

assigns o[0..rows*cols-1];
 */
void transpose(int *a, int *o, int rows, int cols) {
  int r = 0;
  /*@
    loop invariant 0 <= r <= rows;
    loop invariant \forall int i; \forall int j; 0 <= i < r && 0 <= j < cols ==> o[i*cols+j] == a[j*rows+i];
    loop assigns r, o[0..rows*cols-1];
    loop variant rows - r;
  */
  for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    /*@
      loop invariant 0 <= c <= cols;
      loop invariant \forall int i; \forall int j; 0 <= i < r && 0 <= j < cols ==> o[i*cols+j] == a[j*rows+i];
      loop invariant \forall int j; 0 <= j < c ==> o[r*cols+j] == a[j*rows+r];
      loop assigns c, o[r*cols..(r+1)*cols-1];
      loop variant cols - c;
    */
    for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
      o[r*cols+c] = a[c*rows+r];
    }
  }
}
```

My question is for work-around to dealing with memory separation, using transpose as a benchmark. This is why I am wondering how one would even go about formulating the correctness criterion here and proving it.

Comment: What exactly have you tried regarding "carrying [the ensures] as loop invariants"? I can't see any loop invariant directly related to it, which explains why WP can't prove it. Your issues about separation are also quite unclear, but you might want to have a look at the `+ref` memory model (see [WP manual](http://frama-c.com/download/frama-c-wp-manual.pdf) for more information)

Comment: I added an example attempt.

Comment: I also tried an example with an inductive definition that tries to capture unchanges similar to https://github.com/namin/lms-verify/blob/master/src/out/shonan1.c but could not get it to go through, so asking about a specific challenging example but looking for general advice or patterns I might have missed (I don't think this should be so hard...).

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I believe some of the indices-related properties you need to prove are out of the linear arithmetics fragment, for which SMT provers are very strong at proving things automatically. Also, did you try your example with a real 2-dimensions array instead of a flat array mapped to a matrix?

Comment: Makes sense. The 2-dim version has its own woes, with more separation logic, though easier on the arithmetic.